# Android-Reduce the time when retrieving data

Tags: android, time, httprequest

I'm using httpRequest in Android to retrieve and store data from an online shopping website(such as lazada.com.my). Anyhow, I've notice that this method would require several minutes in order to complete the whole httpRequest. I was wondering are there any other method to reduce the time required to retrieve data from an online website as there is no API provided like what eBay provided.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Volley or Square's Retrofit can help for restful communication.  If you are pulling down a lot of images also check out Square's Picasso.  Also are you pulling down too much data at once.  You can look at Lazy Loader methodologies.